# Nginx Rewrite Encoded URI (with percent) Not Working

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress site that needed to 301 redirect old post to new post.

Old post:

```
https://www.example.com/%e0%b8%aa%e0%b8%a7%e0%b8%b1%e0%b8%aa%e0%b8%94%e0%b8%b5/
```

New Post:

```
https://www.example.com/%e0%b8%a5%e0%b8%b2%e0%b8%81%e0%b9%88%e0%b8%ad%e0%b8%99/
```

I added this rule in nginx.conf for this domain here

```
server
{
    listen 111.222.333.444:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com ;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server
{
    rewrite_log on;

    rewrite ^/%e0%b8%aa%e0%b8%a7%e0%b8%b1%e0%b8%aa%e0%b8%94%e0%b8%b5/$ https://www.example.com/%e0%b8%a5%e0%b8%b2%e0%b8%81%e0%b9%88%e0%b8%ad%e0%b8%99/ permanent;

    location / {
      # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
      # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    (the rest of location blocks continue)
}
```

Restart Nginx.
However, the old URL still return 404 and not a 301.

```
https://www.example.com/%e0%b8%aa%e0%b8%a7%e0%b8%b1%e0%b8%aa%e0%b8%94%e0%b8%b5/
```

And I don't see neither old nor new URI in error log at all. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percent encoded URL is available in the `$request_uri` variable. But by the time Nginx is processing `rewrite` and `location` statements, the URL has been [decoded and normalised](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Use a `rewrite` or `location` statement with the decoded values. For example:

```
rewrite ^/สวัสดี/$ /ลาก่อน/ permanent;
```

Or:

```
location = /สวัสดี/ {
    return 301 /ลาก่อน/;
}
```